# rails 4 devise with paperclip, undefined method after_commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid, paperclip

I've got strange problem after devise activation. The model with paperclip attribute has_mongoid_attached_file return exception:

```
undefined method `after_commit' for Item:Class

/home/student/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/paperclip-c9c5227cb7f8/lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb:89:in `add_active_record_callbacks'
/home/student/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/paperclip-c9c5227cb7f8/lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb:19:in `define'
/home/student/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/paperclip-c9c5227cb7f8/lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb:4:in `define_on'
/home/student/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/paperclip-c9c5227cb7f8/lib/paperclip.rb:179:in `has_attached_file'
mongoid-paperclip (0.0.8) lib/mongoid_paperclip.rb:70:in `has_mongoid_attached_file'
```

as I understand the question in visibility of after_commit in gems/paperclip-3.5.3/lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb

```
def add_active_record_callbacks
      name = @name
      @klass.send(:after_save) { send(name).send(:save) }
      @klass.send(:before_destroy) { send(name).send(:queue_all_for_delete) }
      @klass.send(:after_commit, :on => :destroy) { send(name).send(:flush_deletes) }
end
```

In Gemfile I have played with various gems including strong_parameters and protected_attributes but made no progress.

EDIT:
I comment line
@klass.send(:after_commit, :on => :destroy) { send(name).send(:flush_deletes) }
and question now in correct implementation of paperclip with mongoid

EDIT:
found better solution in https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/pull/1425/files

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that paperclip uses an after_commit hook for transactions and Mongoid do not support them. My suggestion is you patch Paperclip to provide a workaround for the transactions.

You could alternatively try [mongoid-paperclip](https://github.com/meskyanichi/mongoid-paperclip), which I think is what you are looking for.